WebSocket Error: 'socket hang up' when connecting to NestJS WebSocketGateway
I try to run simple socket gateway on nest js according official docs https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways.
My Gateway code :
import { WebSocketGateway, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketServer, MessageBody } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(30001)
export class AppGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('test')
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): string {
    return data;
  }
}

app module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AppService, AppGateway],
})
export class AppModule { }

and main which tests itself
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true, httpsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false } });
  await app.listen(3001);
}

function test() {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:30001');


  ws.onopen = function () {
    console.log('open WebSocket');


    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      event: 'test',
      data: { message: 'Hello world!' }
    }));
  };

  ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('Server get messega:', event.data);
  };

  ws.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('Error WebSocket:', error);
  };

  ws.onclose = function () {
    console.log('WebSocket closed');
  };
}

bootstrap();
test();

After run application i see following:
[Nest] 5916  - 23.09.2024, 13:38:42     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 5916  - 23.09.2024, 13:38:42     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 5916  - 23.09.2024, 13:38:42     LOG [WebSocketsController] AppGateway subscribed to the "test" message +35ms
[Nest] 5916  - 23.09.2024, 13:38:42     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +3ms
Error WebSocket: ErrorEvent {
  [Symbol(kTarget)]: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      open: [Function],
      message: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _paused: false,
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 2,
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _autoPong: true,
    _url: 'ws://localhost:30001/',
    _req: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(kError)]: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:471:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:377:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1312:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  },
  [Symbol(kMessage)]: 'socket hang up'
}
WebSocket closed

Whats problem here?I tried another ports,cors etc.Also test socket from postman returns the same error -  socket hang up
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/02-gateways
For that example server running log:
  [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
    [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +21ms
    [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] EventsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
    [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [WebSocketsController] EventsGateway subscribed to the "events" message +62ms
    [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [WebSocketsController] EventsGateway subscribed to the "identity" message +0ms
    [Nest] 1432  - 26.09.2024, 21:30:41     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +4ms
    Application is running on: http://[::1]:3000

And client browser console logs:
Connected
index.html:15 event 1
index.html:15 event 2
index.html:15 event 3
index.html:11 Identity: 0

Seems like all fine.
But when i try to connect via wscat
PS C:\test_gateway\nest\sample\02-gateways> wscat -c ws://localhost:3000
error: socket hang up

Postman the same.

The problem was the default socket adapter is IO.
https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter
After i used the ws adapter all works fine.
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
**import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';**


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  **app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));**
  await app.listen(30001);
}

bootstrap();


maybe you should test with socket client, not the ws

the docs have example to test the socket, you should do like this, try it out

Seems like thats works from the client provided in that test example.But whats problem with  wscat -c ws://localhost:3000
error: socket hang up,for example?

When you’re using @WebSocketGateway() in NestJS, it defaults to Socket.IO instead of the native WebSocket (ws). This is why you cannot connect with native WebSocket using new WebSocket('ws://localhost:30001').

Yes.You are right
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
After using ws adapter all works fine for me
